# How do I display a template with Meteor Iron Router while the user is logging in?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

(When `Meteor.loggingIn()` is true)

Comment: asking for the best way is not a good question, "best" is subjective.  I've edited it so its not so subjective.  You have to assume when people answer the question of "how" to do it that they are offering you what they think is the best way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [custom action function](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/master/DOCS.md#using-a-custom-action-function).

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('postShow', {
    path: '/posts/:_id',

    action: function () {
      if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
        this.render('loggingIn');
      } else {
        this.render();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

When `Meteor.loggingIn()` changes, the action function will reactively rerun.